# How to preserve order of insertion in Map.of factory?

Tags: java, hashmap, java-9, factory-method

Java 9 offers `Map.of()` feature to easily create a map with fixed values.

Problem: I want to create a map that preserves order of insertion like `LinkedHashMap`. Is that possible with that factory? At least `map.of()` does not preserv the order...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There isn't a factory method like `LinkedHashMap::of` indeed, and a `Map` does not have an order per-se, so the only way I see it is to build a `LinkedHashMap` if you really needed one.

Btw from [the JEP itself](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/269):

> Static factory methods on concrete collection classes (e.g., ArrayList, HashSet) have been removed from this proposal ...
>
> There is another wrinkle, which is that static methods on classes are inherited by subclasses. Suppose a static factory method HashMap.of() were to be added. Since LinkedHashMap is a subclass of HashMap, it would be possible for application code to call LinkedHashMap.of(). This would end up calling HashMap.of(), not at all what one would expect!

Point here is that `static` methods are inherited, but not overridable, thus if such a method would have been added to `HashMap` it could have not been overridden in `LinkedHashMap`.

If you can use `guava`, you could use `ImmutableMap` that is documented as:

> An immutable, hash-based Map with reliable user-specified iteration order...

Comment: On the last edit, I've noticed this in quite a few places and would want to learn if `LinkedHashMap` and Guava's `ImmutableMap` has any comparative analysis that I can go through? I couldn't though sense anything other than immutability.

Comment: @nullpointer I am no aware of such analysis, I seem to trust guava quite a lot :| what I like is that it is build using a one-liner, as opposed `Collections::unmodifiableMap` that would wrap a `LinkedHashMap`...

Comment: My upvote for ImmutableMap. That's the best solution IMO.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov I wish I could return this upvote for the proposed names for `BiCollector`...

Comment: Actually, `static` methods are overridable, i.e. if `LinkedHashMap` provided such factory methods with the same signature as in `HashMap`, they would override them, so `LinkedHashMap.of(…)` would end up at the right method, *if* `LinkedHashMap` provides such a method. You could assume that this would be the case when both classes stem from the same JRE, but what about a `ThirdPartyMap` inheriting from either of these classes. The worst thing would be, if it gets adapted to provide factory methods *once*, to end up with a mixture of overridden and non-overridden methods in a future JRE version…

Comment: @Holger to be pedantic, they can be hidden [(8.4.8.2. Hiding (by Class Methods))](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.2), not overridden [8.4.8.1. Overriding (by Instance Methods))](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1), but your point still holds - it could have been done, but it would have incurred a significant implementation- and maintainance cost.

Comment: @Hulk indeed, and even `javac` fails to use the correct terminology, e.g. in its error messages. That one time I didn’t consult the specification, it immediately bites me…

Comment: @Holger I love those btw! :) when you have a `final static method` in Parent and the same signature in Child (without `final`) - `javac` will say something like overridable method is final

Answer (score 5):

As documented on the Java apidoc of [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) (emphasis mine):

> ## Unmodifiable Maps
>
> The `Map.of`, `Map.ofEntries`, and `Map.copyOf` static factory methods
>   provide a convenient way to create unmodifiable maps. The Map
>   instances created by these methods have the following characteristics:
>
> - ...
> - The **iteration order of mappings is unspecified** and is subject to change.
> - ...

Unfortunately, there is no equivalent convenience method in the Java API that creates a `LinkedHashMap`. If you want a consistent iteration order, then you will need to manually create a `LinkedHashMap` and populate it (and - if needed - wrap it using `Collections.unmodifiableMap`).

Consider creating your own convenience method that does the equivalent of `Map.of` but with a consistent iteration order (or find an existing library that already provides this).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use vavr.io in the following way:

```
Map<String, String> mapPreservingInsertionOrder = io.vavr.collection.LinkedHashMap.of("key1", "val1", "key2", "val2").toJavaMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there seems to be no method that is doing what you want in the JDK you have to implement it by yourself or use a existing library. Creating such helper method isn't that hard:

```
public static <K, V> LinkedHashMap<K, V> of(Collection<Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>> entries) {
  final LinkedHashMap<K, V> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  entries.forEach(entry -> map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
  return map;
}
```

And then you could use it like this:

```
of(List.of(Map.entry("Hello", "World"), Map.entry("Goodnight", "Moon")));
```

This solution has the advantage over the Map.of in the JDK that the key value pairs are provided as entry pairs and not just as lose pairs by parameter index.

Comment: nice, but for consistency the method would better be named ofEntries

Answer (score -1):

Plain vanilla Java 8 (or newer) without anonymous class:

```java
import static java.text.MessageFormat.format;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Snippet {

    public static final Map<String, String> MAP = Stream.of(
        new SimpleEntry<>("key1", "value1"),
        new SimpleEntry<>("key0", "value0"),
        new SimpleEntry<>("key3", "value3"),
        new SimpleEntry<>("key2", "value2")
    ).collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> { throw new AssertionError(format("Duplicate key with values ''{0}'', ''{1}''!", a, b)); }, LinkedHashMap::new));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MAP.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(format("{0}={1}", k, v)));
    }
}
```